# how to integrate my site to facebook

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I want to integrate my site to the Facebook login system. I googled it and at last I find this [great tutorial](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/).

But there is a problem in my authentication. [Here](http://www.cpantry.com/match/) you can find my test site. I have used php-sdk; please help where I make a mistake.

```
<?php
    include_once "fbmain.php";
    $config['baseurl']  =   "http://www.cpantry.com/match/index.php";

    //if user is logged in and session is valid.
    if ($fbme){
        //Retriving movies those are user like using graph api
        try{
            $movies = $facebook->api('/me/movies');
        }
        catch(Exception $o){
            d($o);
        }

        //Calling users.getinfo legacy api call example
        try{
            $param  =   array(
                'method'  => 'users.getinfo',
                'uids'    => $fbme['id'],
                'fields'  => 'name,current_location,profile_url',
                'callback'=> ''
            );
            $userInfo   =   $facebook->api($param);
        }
        catch(Exception $o){
            d($o);
        }

        //update user's status using graph api
        if (isset($_POST['tt'])){
            try {
                $statusUpdate = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array('message'=> $_POST['tt'], 'cb' => ''));
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                d($e);
            }
        }

        //fql query example using legacy method call and passing parameter
        try{
            //get user id
            $uid    = $facebook->getUser();
            //or you can use $uid = $fbme['id'];

            $fql    =   "select name, hometown_location, sex, pic_square from user where uid=" . $uid;
            $param  =   array(
                'method'    => 'fql.query',
                'query'     => $fql,
                'callback'  => ''
            );
            $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
        }
        catch(Exception $o){
            d($o);
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>PHP SDK & Graph API base FBConnect Tutorial | Thinkdiff.net
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({appId: '<?=$fbconfig['appid' ]?>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

                /* All the events registered */
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                    // do something with response
                    login();
                });
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
                    // do something with response
                    logout();
                });
            };
            (function() {
                var e = document.createElement('script');
                e.type = 'text/javascript';
                e.src = document.location.protocol +
                    '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
                e.async = true;
                document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
            }());

            function login(){
                document.location.href = "";
            }
            function logout(){
                document.location.href = "";
            }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .box{
        margin: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #60729b;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 500px;
        height: 200px;
        overflow:auto;
        background-color: #e6ebf8;
    }
</style>

    <h3>PHP SDK & Graph API base FBConnect Tutorial | Thinkdiff.net
    <?php if (!$fbme) { ?>
        You've to login using FB Login Button to see api calling result.
    <?php } ?>
    <p>
        <fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" perms="email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream">
    </p>

    <!-- all time check if user session is valid or not -->
    <?php if ($fbme){ ?>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <!-- Data retrived from user profile are shown here -->
                <div class="box">
                    <b>User Information using Graph API
                    <?php d($fbme); ?>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="box">
                    <b>User likes these movies | using graph api
                     <?php d($movies); ?>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="box">
                    <b>User Information by Calling Legacy API method "users.getinfo"
                    <?php d($userInfo); ?>
                </div>
            
            <td>
                <div class="box">
                    <b>FQL Query Example by calling Legacy API method "fql.query"
                    <?php d($fqlResult); ?>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="box">
        <form name="" action="<?=$config['baseurl']?>" method="post">
            <label for="tt">Status update using Graph API
            <br />
            <textarea id="tt" name="tt" cols="50" rows="5">Write your status here and click 'submit'
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Update My Status" />
        </form>
        <?php if (isset($statusUpdate)) { ?>
            <br />
            <b style="color: red">Status Updated Successfully! Status id is 
         <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please post your relevant code here

Comment: Not meant as an attack against the OP, but +2 upvotes for a question with *zero* relevant info, no source code to work with, and no possibility to give a meaningful answer? Who does this? I am beginning to lose faith in Stack Overflow's community.

Comment: @Pekka. whoes hobby is to vote n vote n vote n vote.

Comment: Providing a link to the tutorial you based your work on is helpful, but only so much, and not as helpful as seeing your actual code. The code in the tutorial, after all, works. Your code doesn't. So your code must be different. Sending us to the tutorial to figure out why is like sending a friend to the doctor to find out what is wrong with you. Doesn't work...

Comment: ok i update my question and my code also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the fact that your demo page still contains the original content from the ThinkDiff.net website, and in accordance with [Ockham's Razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ockham%27s_razor), I will ask - have you updated the contents of the files from the tutorial to reflect the credentials for your own website?

In **fbmain.php** have you updated

```
$fbconfig['appid' ]  = "your application id";
$fbconfig['api'   ]  = "your application api key";
$fbconfig['secret']  = "your application secret key";
```

with your Facebook Application ID, API key and Secret Key?

In **index.php** have you updated

```
$config['baseurl']  =   "http://thinkdiff.net/demo/newfbconnect1/php/index.php";
```

to your own URL for the index.php file's location?

Failure to do these things (specifically the first set) will, of course, cause an authentication error when you try and execute a Facebook Login.

---

### Update - Reviewed the Output of the Demo Page

Firstly, the content of the demo page appears quite different from the demo files associated with the tutorial. Anyway, having looked at the page, I noticed the below line of javascript:

```
newwindow=window.open('https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=109479982464493&cancel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fthinkdiff.net%2Fdemo%2Fnewfbconnect1%2Fphp%2Findex.php%3Fcancel%3D1&display=popup&fbconnect=1&next=http%3A%2F%2Fthinkdiff.net%2Fdemo%2Fnewfbconnect1%2Fphp%2Findex.php%3Floginsucc%3D1&return_session=1&session_version=3&v=1.0&req_perms=email%2Cuser_birthday','Login_by_facebook',features);
```

As suspected - the "thinkdiff.net" content is still present in your code somewhere.

**Do a search for "thinkdiff" in all of your code, and, as you do, replace it with the correct content.**

Comment: yeah i have updated all the credentials and also updated baseurl i.e you can see in my code

Comment: I have looked at your output code on your demo site - see my modified answer.

Comment: i checked my code but not find **"thinkdiff"** anywhere in my code. i pulled my hair with this code from last 5 hour but no success yet.

Comment: @hunter: That is not how StackOverflow works - we help you find the solution rather than generate the solution for you. You can always include the content of all your various files (after you remove your APP ID and other keys) in your question, and we may find the problem them.

Comment: @hunter: I just rechecked your demo page - the above-noted content is now gone. Good. And a Facebook popup is shown when I click the "Login" button. Good too. I can see the error being generated, though. It is probably the APP ID, one of your keys, or a configuration setting within your App which is to blame now. Triple-check them all. Then check them again.

Comment: i checked the keys ten times but what about the **configuration setting** you mentioned

Comment: i got it finally update my configuration setting any thank you very much Lucanos for your time..... Oh kho,